# Overlapping and too long integer values in dynamic c structs

Tags: c, printf, buffer

I have the following problem.
I need to create a list of savestates with dynamical length. That's why I decided to create a list by defining some structs and connecting dynamically created structs together to build a list of structs which can dynamically be extended and so on.
However, some things seem to not work at all. Here's the relevant code first:

saves.h:

```
#ifndef SAVES_H
#include<time.h>
#define SAVES_H
#define SVS_STRLEN 500
#define SVS_FILE "savefile.dat"
#define True 1
#define False 0
typedef struct SVS_STATE SVS_STATE;
typedef struct SVS_STATES SVS_STATES;

struct SVS_STATE {
    int i_playfield[6][7];
    int i_turn;
    time_t i_time;
    void *next;
};

struct SVS_STATES {
    SVS_STATE *states;
    int count;
    int loaded;
};

void SVS_Add_State(int i_playfield[][7], int i_turn, time_t i_time);
void SVS_Debug_State(SVS_STATE *state);
void SVS_Format_State(SVS_STATE *state, char text[]);
SVS_STATE *SVS_Get_State(int number);
#endif
```

saves.c:

```
#include "saves.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

SVS_STATE *SVS_Get_State(int number)
{
    int i = 1;
    SVS_STATE *state;
    if (svs_current_state.loaded == False) return NULL;
    if (number > svs_current_state.count) return NULL;
    state = svs_current_state.states;
    printf("printing state 1:");
    SVS_Debug_State(state);
    while( i < number)
    {
        i++;
        state = (SVS_STATE*)(state->next);
        printf("printing state %i:", i);
        SVS_Debug_State(state);
    }
    return state;
}

void SVS_Format_State(SVS_STATE *state, char text[])
{
    int i, j;
    if (svs_current_state.loaded == False) return;
    text[0] = '\0';
    strcat(text, "{\0");
    for (i = 0; i < X_SIZE; i++)
    {
        strcat(text, "{\0");
        for(j = 0; j < Y_SIZE; j++)
        {
            strcat(text, "%i,\0");
            sprintf(text, text, state->i_playfield[i][j]);
        }
        strcat(text, "}\0");
    }
    strcat(text, "};%i;%i\n\0");
    sprintf(text, text, state->i_turn, state->i_time);
    printf("\nFormatted state:%s\n", text);
}

void SVS_Debug_State(SVS_STATE *state)
{
    char text[SVS_STRLEN];
    SVS_Format_State(state, text);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}

void SVS_Add_State(int i_playfield[][7], int i_turn, time_t i_time)
{
    int i, j;
    SVS_STATE *laststate, *newstate;
    newstate = (SVS_STATE*)malloc(sizeof(SVS_STATE));
    printf("adding state with time:%i\n", i_time);
    if (svs_current_state.loaded == False) return;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            newstate->i_playfield[i][j] = i_playfield[i][j];
    newstate->i_turn = i_turn;
    newstate->i_time = i_time;
    newstate->next = NULL;
    printf("initialized state:");
    SVS_Debug_State(newstate);
    if (svs_current_state.coun > 0)
    {
        laststate = SVS_Get_State(svs_current_state.count);
        laststate->next = (void*)newstate;
    } else
        svs_current_state.states=newstate;
    svs_current_state.count++;
}

int main()
{
    int i_playfield[6][7] = {0};
    // mark saves library as loaded here, but removed function, since it
    // just sets svs_current_state.loaded (which is the global struct of
    // type SVS_STATES) to 1
    SVS_Add_State(i_playfield, 1, time(NULL));
    i_playfield[0][0] = 2;
    SVS_Add_State(i_playfield, 2, time(NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

The actual problems I encountered while using the printf's and Debug_State calls in these functions:
- the i_time I give is printed out once in Add_State(), correctly. Means it is a legal time and stuff, but when printed out after creating the full state by using Format_State() the string is 50 percent to long and the last part is displayed twice, for example:
if the time is 12345678, it is displayed correctly while debugging in Add_State, but Format_State() displays 123456785678.
- second problem: the first state added works, more or less, fine. But after adding a second one, printing the first state (retrieved by using Get_State and formatted with Format_State) prints a mixture of two states, for example something like this:

```
state 1: {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}...
{0,0,0,0,0,0}};1;123456785678
state 2: {{0,0,0,0,0,0}{0,0,0,0,0,0}...
{0,0,0,0,0,0}};2;1234567856785678,0}{0,0,0,0,0,0}...
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: the code does not compile one reason is the missing '#include <stdio.h>'  another reason is 'svs_current_state' not defined.   There are many more problems in the code.   Please correct and repost

Comment: in struct SVS_STATE, the 'next' field is typed as void*  it should be typed as struct SVS_STATE *next;   the items X_SIZE and Y_SIZE are not defined

Comment: In C, when calling malloc(), and family of functions, 1) do not cast the returned value.   2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: for reading/understanding of the code, by humans, separate code blocks by a blank line, declare only one variable per line,

Comment: Functions like 'SVS_Add_State()' should be modified to return an indication of success/failure, otherwise the rest of the program does not know that a failure occurred.

Comment: this line: 'if (svs_current_state.loaded == False) return;' in function SVS_Add_State() will result in a memory leak because the pointer to the just malloc'd memory will be lost. Suggest checking/returning before the call to malloc().  There is no reason to define 'True' and 'False', just use true and false.  However, this kind of line: 'if (svs_current_state.loaded == False ) return;' would be better written as: 'if (!svs_current_state.loaded ) return;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls

```
sprintf(text, text, ...
```

invoke undefined behaviour, as the target buffer and one of the other arguments overlap.

From the [POSIX specs to `sprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html):

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap as a result of a call to *sprintf()* [...], the results are undefined.